# Show that the following sets are closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

Show that the following sets are closed:

(a) $A = \{f ∈ C_{c}(\mathbb{R}) |\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t) dt = 0\}$,
where $g \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ is fixed. Here, we are considering the $sup-$norm. Show that $A$ is closed in $C_{c}(\mathbb{R}).$

(b)  $B = \{f ∈ L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) |\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t) dt = 0\}$,
where $g \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is fixed. Show that $B$ is closed in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

**My attempt:**

(a) We know that completion of $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ is $C_{0}(\mathbb{R}).$ Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence in $A$ such that $f_{n}$ converges to a function $f$ in $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ uniformly, then how do we show that $f\in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$?.

If I assume the part where I got stuck, then I will be able to solve the rest of the problem by considering an interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(t)g(t)=0$,  $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus [a,b]$ and then proceeding using continuity.

(b) I tried to proceed using sequences here as well but I am stuck in the integral part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Closed in what space? $A$ is definitely not, in general, closed in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have made the necessary edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a).

We don't have to show that $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$. If it were $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R})\setminus C_c(\mathbb{R})$ then $f_n$ wouldn't converge in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$. Since we are in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, all the functions can converge **only** to functions in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$.

For b).

Observe that $f\in B \iff \langle f, g\rangle = 0$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Since $f\mapsto \langle f, g\rangle$ is a continuous function, it follows that $B$ is closed as preimage of a closed set $\{0\}$ under this function.